# Received data from a file and need to print it, but program isn't reading the data properly?

Tags: c, io

In my program I have to print a general journal with data coming from 2 files, 'accounts.dat' and 'transactions.dat'

accounts.dat has:

```
1000:first
2000:second
3000:hello
```

transactions.dat has

```
1000:first:d:1000.000000
2000:second:c:1500.000000
3000:hello:d:1000.000000
```

So basically the same data except transactions has 2 more.

When I checked my read function which scans the file data and inputs it into arrays that are in the program, they're there but when I call the generaljournal function to print it in a specific format, the general journal does not acknowledge the files that are scanned into my arrays.

the function is:

```
void generaljournal(int accounts[MAX], int accounts3[MAX], char debcred[MAX], double amount[MAX], char accname[MAX][MAXSTRING], char transname[MAX][MAXSTRING], int *totalinput) {

int i = 0;

printf ("\n");
printf ("\t\t\tGeneral Journal\n");
printf ("Account  Description                          Debit      Credit\n");
printf ("-------  ------------------------------  ----------  ----------\n");


for (i = 0; i < *totalinput; i++)
{
    printf ("   %d", accounts[i]);


    if (debcred[i] == 'd')
    {
        printf ("  %-35s", transname[i]);
        printf ("%.2lf\n", amount[i]);
    }


    else if (debcred[i] == 'c')
    {
        printf ("  %-47s", transname[i]);
        printf ("%.2lf\n", amount[i]);
    }

}

printf ("\n");

}
```

All the arrays that are called has the data in the arrays but aren't being printed when I call the general journal function. I call the read function in my main but even if I put the

```
read(accounts, accounts3, debcred, amount, accname, transname);
```

In my general journal function it still doesn't do anything. 
What the output SHOULD look like is something like

```
Account     Description     Debit     Credit
1000        first           1000.000
2000        second                    1500.00
3000        hello           1000.00
```

Instead it prints just the shell of (accounts, description, debit, credit) with no values underneath.

Does anyone know why it's not accepting the values in the arrays when I scanned it all from the files in my read function? If more information is needed i'll supply. My read function is:

```
void read (int accounts[MAX], int accounts3[MAX], char debcred[MAX], double amount[MAX], char accname[MAX][MAXSTRING], char transname[MAX][MAXSTRING]) {

FILE *fp1 = NULL;
FILE *fp2 = NULL;

fp1 = fopen("accounts.dat", "r");
fp2 = fopen("transactions.dat", "r");

int h = 0;



if (fp1 != NULL) // READING THE FILE
{
    while(fscanf(fp1, "%d", &accounts[h]) != EOF)
    {

            fgetc(fp1);
            fscanf(fp1, "%30[^\n]", &accname[h]);
            h++;
    }

    fclose(fp1);
}
else
    printf ("Failed to open file\n");



if (fp2 != NULL) // READING THE FILE
{
    int j = 0;
    while(fscanf(fp2, "%d", &accounts3[j]) != EOF)
    {
        fgetc(fp2);
        fscanf(fp2, "%30[^:]", &transname[j]);
        fgetc(fp2);
        fscanf(fp2, "%c", &debcred[j]);
        fgetc(fp2);
        fscanf(fp2, "%lf", &amount[j]);
        j++;
    }

    fclose(fp2);
}
else
    printf ("Failed to open file\n");

}
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of *totalinput?

Comment: This must be the problem...fixing now will come back for update

Comment: after doing some changes it wasn't printing anything cause when i opened the program again totalinput was 0 so it wasn't printing anything! Thank you sir! @fnokke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the value of `*totalinput` is `0`